# Does Funq support ResolveAll?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, funq

Does the Funq IoC container support resolving all registrations for a type?  Something like either of these:

```
IEnumerable<IFoo> foos = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IFoo>>();
IEnumerable<IFoo> foos = container.ResolveAll<IFoo>();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Funq does not have a `ResolveAll` method, but you can simply register an `IEnumerable<IFoo>` and resolve it with `Resolve<IEnumerable<IFoo>>()` as you show in your question.

In general however, it is better *not* to request the container for collections, but use [composites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) instead. This way you can simply inject an `IFoo` as a dependency, instead of forcing consumers of that dependency to iterate the list. Instead you embed the code that loops the list of `IFoo` instances inside the composite. This keeps your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and doesn't force you to go through the (possible) dozens of `foreach (var foo in foos)` statements scattered throughout the application, when a change has to be made in the way the items are iterated. Or let me put it in an other way: it is not the responsibility of a consumer to know how to iterate all `IFoo`s.

Here is an example of an `IFoo` Composite:

```cs
// A composite is something that implements an interface
// (in this case IFoo) and wraps a list of items of that
// same interface.
public class FooComposite : IFoo
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IFoo> foos;

    public FooComposite(params IFoo[] foos)
    {
        this.foos = foos;
    }

    void IFoo.FooThatThing(IBar bar)
    {
        foreach (var foo in this.foos)
        {
            foo.FooThatThing(bar);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of registering an `IEnumerable<IFoo>`, you can register a `CompositeFoo` as `IFoo`:

```cs
container.Register<IFoo>(c => new CompositeFoo(
    new Foo1(), new Foo2(), new Foo3()));
```

Now you can let the container inject that `CompositeFoo` in consumers that take an `IFoo` argument, which makes them unaware that they are in fact dealing with a list of `IFoo` elements.

**UPDATE**:

Using this composite pattern, you can easily control the lifetime of each `IFoo` item. It's just a matter of calling back into the container. With Funq,it would look like this:

```cs
container.Register<IFoo>(c => new CompositeFoo(
    c.Resolve<Foo1>(),
    c.Resolve<Foo2>(),
    c.Resolve<Foo3>()));
```

This way you can register `Foo1` as singleton and `Foo2` as transient for instance. When the `CompositeFoo` is reused however, `Foo2` will not really be transient, but it's just a matter of changing the `CompositeFoo` and its registration to solve this problem. For instance, you can change your `CompositeFoo` to the following:

```cs
public class FooComposite : IFoo
{
    private readonly Func<IFoo>[] fooFactories;

    public FooComposite(params Func<IFoo>[] fooFactories)
    {
        this.fooFactories = fooFactories;
    }

    void IFoo.FooThatThing(IBar bar)
    {
        foreach (var fooFactory in this.fooFactories)
        {
            var foo = fooFactory();

            foo.FooThatThing(bar);
        }
    }
}
```

Now instead of injecting some `IFoo`s into the constructor, we can inject some lambdas in it:

```cs
container.Register<IFoo>(c => new CompositeFoo(
    () => c.Resolve<Foo1>(),
    () => c.Resolve<Foo2>(),
    () => c.Resolve<Foo3>()));
```

This will ensure that every time `CompositeFoo`'s `FooThatThing` is called, the container is queried for new `IFoo` instances. This allows `FooThatThing` to be called multiple times by the same consumer, and even allows `CompositeFoo` to be registered as singleton.

This advice holds for all containers and Dependency Injection in general, and is not specific to the use of Funq.

Comment: Thanks for the answer about Funq, Steven. Your use of composition is a good work around, but I don't agree with using it generally for any container.  What about when I need to control the life cycle of each registrant differently? The consumer is not forced to iterate the list - they can always resolve a single instance when needed - it is their choice.  Also, Common Service Locator http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/ explicitly implements multiple resolution in GetAllInstances().

Comment: @Sean: The fact the Common Service Locator contains a `GetAllInstances`, doesn't directly make it a good practice to use it ([Service Locator is by itself an anti-pattern](http://bit.ly/a7lU76)). In fact, the [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com) (a container I develop) contains a `GetAllInstances` method, but in I advice against using it in most cases (however, it is useful within the [Composition Root](http://bit.ly/pHCoS7)). Furthermore, when you need to control the lifetime of each element in the composite, it is a matter of changing the registration. See my update.

Comment: What if I'm building a pipeline of request and response processors and I have 30-40 of each? Is there no way to just say give me all implementations of IProcessor without registering every single one individually?

Comment: Jack, it's time to start using a real  DI Container.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want the anti-pattern, simply because you might not want to implement a factory pattern, here is my version based on last 3.9.71.

Only downside is that it adds a bit more memory and you have to register the services through registerOneOfMany(). you might want to change the bag for a list with a lock (for faster reads) and switch to servicstack funq's default: `ReuseScope.Default`

```
public static class FunqExtensions
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type,ConcurrentBag<string>> registrations = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConcurrentBag<string>>();

    public static void RegisterOneOfMany<TBase, TImplementation>(this Container container, string name = null, ReuseScope scope  = ReuseScope.None) where TImplementation : TBase
    {
        if (name == null)
            name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var funq = Container.GenerateAutoWireFn<TImplementation>();
        container.Register<TBase>(name, (c) => funq(c))
          .ReusedWithin(scope);
        registrations.GetOrAdd(typeof(TBase), type => new ConcurrentBag<string>()).Add(name);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> ResolveAll<T>(this Container container)
    {
        ConcurrentBag<string> result;
        if (registrations.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out result))
        {
            var rator = result.GetEnumerator();
            while (rator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return container.ResolveNamed<T>(rator.Current);
            }
        }
    }  
}
```